# Like function not works in url management

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii

My project is Yii framework. I have problem in like function in URL management system. without URL management it was working fine. after i changed the URL manager its not working. i added my code following. pl suggest me what needs to be change.

```
 <span>     
   <?php 
   $image = '<img class="span myfacvoriteadd" id="like" src="'.Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/like.png'.'"  onclick="change(this.id,<?php  echo $rec_id ; ?>);"/>';

   echo CHtml::link($image);  ?>


    <p id='result1<?php echo $rec_id; ?>'><?php echo $like ;?>

    </p>                        
          </span>
```

earlier my code was following:

```
<span>
                       <img src="images/like.png"  class="img-responsive" id="like" onclick="change(this.id,<?php  echo $rec_id ; ?>)">
                     <p id='result1<?php echo $rec_id; ?>'><?php echo $like ;?></p>                        
                      </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are opening and closing php tag ***in*** php code, change the third line to :

```
   $image = '<img class="span myfacvoriteadd" 
             id="like" 
             src="'.Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/like.png'.'"  
             onclick="change(this.id,'.$rec_id.');"
             />';
```

Comment: <?php $image = '<img class="span myfacvoriteadd" 
             id="like"  src="'.Yii::app()->baseUrl.'/images/like.png'.'"  
             onclick="change(this.id,'.$rec_id.');" />'; ?>  i added your code but image are not displayed

Comment: what do you see when you try to `echo $image` ??

Comment: ya its working fine. thank you ur support. please give me vote for my question also